# Table transformation / field parsing in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have de-normalized table, something like

```
CODES

ID  | VALUE
10  | A,B,C
11  | A,B
12  | A,B,C,D,E,F
13  | R,T,D,W,W,W,W,W,S,S
```

The job is to convert is where each token from VALUE will generate new row. Example:

```
CODES_TRANS

ID  | VALUE_TRANS
10  | A
10  | B
10  | C
11  | A
11  | B
```

What is the best way to do it in PL/SQL without usage of custom pl/sql packages, ideally with pure SQL?

Obvious solution is to implement it via cursors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative is to use the model clause:

```
SQL> select id
  2       , value
  3    from codes
  4   model
  5         return updated rows
  6         partition by (id)
  7         dimension by (-1 i)
  8         measures (value)
  9         ( value[for i from 0 to length(value[-1])-length(replace(value[-1],',')) increment 1]
 10           = regexp_substr(value[-1],'[^,]+',1,cv(i)+1)
 11         )
 12   order by id
 13       , i
 14  /

        ID VALUE
---------- -------------------
        10 A
        10 B
        10 C
        11 A
        11 B
        12 A
        12 B
        12 C
        12 D
        12 E
        12 F
        13 R
        13 T
        13 D
        13 W
        13 W
        13 W
        13 W
        13 W
        13 S
        13 S

21 rows selected.
```

I have written up to 6 alternatives for this type of query in this blogpost: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2007/11/interval-based-row-generation.html

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Slick solution Rob. I find `model` hard to intuit, so it's never the first thing I turn to.  Nice blog post too.

Comment: +1 and accepted - very cool! This is more generic solution than mine

Comment: @be here now: No. The SQL model clause was introduced in version 10. In the link there are some alternatives that work in version 9.

Answer (score 3):

I have a pure SQL solution for you.

I adapted a trick I found on [an old Ask Tom site, posted by Mihail Bratu](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:55423584511523).  My adaptation uses regex to tokenise the VALUE column, so it requires 10g or higher.

The test data.

```
SQL> select * from t34
  2  /

        ID VALUE
---------- -------------------------
        10 A,B,C
        11 A,B
        12 A,B,C,D,E,F
        13 R,T,D,W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,S,S

SQL>
```

The query:

```
SQL> select   t34.id
  2            , t.column_value value
  3  from t34
  4       , table(cast(multiset(
  5              select regexp_substr (t34.value, '[^(,)]+', 1, level)
  6              from dual
  7              connect by level <= length(value)
  8         ) as sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll )) t
  9  where t.column_value != ','
 10  /

        ID VALUE
---------- -------------------------
        10 A
        10 B
        10 C
        11 A
        11 B
        12 A
        12 B
        12 C
        12 D
        12 E
        12 F
        13 R
        13 T
        13 D
        13 W1
        13 W2
        13 W3
        13 W4
        13 W5
        13 S
        13 S

21 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm getting weird errors when I try to run this; are you sure about "as sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll"?

Comment: sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll is a type, defined as "table of varchar2(1000)".

Comment: @IMHO - sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll has been around since 9iR2.  What "weird" errors are you getting?  Come to that, what version of Oracle DB are you using?

Comment: i'm using 10g and I'm getting: "No more data to read from socket" on first run, "OALL8 is in an inconsistent state" on second run...

Answer (score 1):

Based on Celko's book, here is what I found and it's working well!

```
  SELECT 
    TABLE1.ID
    , MAX(SEQ1.SEQ) AS START_POS
    , SEQ2.SEQ AS END_POS
    , COUNT(SEQ2.SEQ) AS PLACE
  FROM 
    TABLE1, V_SEQ SEQ1, V_SEQ SEQ2
  WHERE 
    SUBSTR(',' || TABLE1.VALUE || ',', SEQ1.SEQ, 1) = ','
    AND SUBSTR(',' || TABLE1.VALUE || ',', SEQ2.SEQ, 1) = ','
    AND SEQ1.SEQ < SEQ2.SEQ
    AND SEQ2.SEQ <= LENGTH(TABLE1.VALUE)
  GROUP BY TABLE1.ID, TABLE1.VALUE, SEQ2.SEQ
```

Where V_SEQ is a static table with one field:

```
SEQ, integer values 1 through N, where N >= MAX_LENGTH(VALUE).
```

This is based on the fact the the VALUE is wrapped by ',' on both ends, like this:

```
,A,B,C,D,
```

If your tokens are fixed length (like in my case) I simply used PLACE field to calculate the actual string. If variable length, use start_pos and end_pos

So, in my case, tokens are 2 char long, so the final SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE1.ID
    , SUBSTR(TABLE1.VALUE, T_SUB.PLACE * 3 - 2 , 2 ) AS SINGLE_VAL
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    TABLE1.ID
    , MAX(SEQ1.SEQ) AS START_POS
    , SEQ2.SEQ AS END_POS
    , COUNT(SEQ2.SEQ) AS PLACE
  FROM 
    TABLE1, V_SEQ SEQ1, V_SEQ SEQ2
  WHERE 
    SUBSTR(',' || TABLE1.VALUE || ',', SEQ1.SEQ, 1) = ','
    AND SUBSTR(',' || TABLE1.VALUE || ',', SEQ2.SEQ, 1) = ','
    AND SEQ1.SEQ < SEQ2.SEQ
    AND SEQ2.SEQ <= LENGTH(TABLE1.VALUE)
  GROUP BY TABLE1.ID, TABLE1.VALUE, SEQ2.SEQ
) T_SUB
INNER JOIN 
  TABLE1 ON TABLE1.ID = T_SUB.ID
ORDER BY TABLE1.ID, T_SUB.PLACE
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

In SQL Server TSQL we parse strings and make a table object. Here is sample code - maybe you can translate it.

http://rbgupta.blogspot.com/2007/10/tsql-parsing-delimited-string-into.html

**Second Option**

Count the number of commas per row. Get the Max number of commas. Let's say that in the entire table you have a row with 5 commas max. Build a SELECT with 5 substrings. This will make it a set based operation and should be much faster than a rbar.

Comment: well, i know how to do this - the issue is that this is very slow since it has to do record level processing

Comment: second option won't work - I may have 20 or 30 tokens

however, I think I found a solution in Celko's book, similar to what u r suggesting. I will test and post the solution if it works